# Excel VBA :: Copying values using a loop & run time error 9

Tags: excel, for-loop, runtime-error, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA, so the following question should not be too difficult. But since I spent about one and a half hour about the code, I think I simply lack some basic understanding how it should look like so I thought it's worth posting it here.

What the code is doing is basically copying values from one range in one sheet to another range in another sheet in the same active workbook containing some kind of a schedule.

I get a "run-time error '9' subscript out of range" error message already in the very first run through the loop in the section

```
'Subject
Morning = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day)
```

I tried out the code in a blank workbook so the error should not be due to formatting (in case this might have been the cause). But if you need more information about the context etc. I can provide of course more details.

Thank you for your answers!

Patrick

```
Sub SetData_new()
' SubModule to copy the data from 'Master_Plan' to particular sheets

Dim CurrWS As Long, StartWS As Long, EndWS As Long
StartWS = Sheets("W_1").Index
EndWS = Sheets("L_1").Index
Dim Weeknr As Integer
Weeknr = 5
Dim Day As Long
Dim Morning As Range, Afternoon As Range, Noon As Range

For CurrWS = StartWS To EndWS

   'Set updated ranges
   Set Morning = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(4, 4)
   Set Afternoon = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(8, 4)
   Set Noon = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(12, 4)

    For Day = 3 To 21 Step 3
    'Subject
       Morning = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day)
       Afternoon = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day)
       Noon = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day)

     'Category
       Morning.Offset(0, 1) = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day + 1)
       Afternoon.Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day + 1)
       Noon.Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day + 1)

     'Type
       Morning.Offset(0, 2) = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day + 2)
       Afternoon.Offset(0, 2).Value = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day + 2)
   Noon.Offset(0, 2).Value = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day + 2)

     'Specifications
       Morning.Offset(0, 3) = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 3, Day)
       Afternoon.Offset(0, 3).Value = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 5, Day)
       Noon.Offset(0, 3).Value = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 7, Day)

     'Increment
       Morning = Morning.Offset(12, 0)
       Afternoon = Afternoon.Offset(12, 0)
       Noon = Noon.Offset(12, 0)
     Next Day

    Wochennummer = Wochennummer + 9
Next CurrWS

Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: A couple of basic issues to fix first: you need to explicitly spcify type for each variable in a `DIM` (otherwise the variable will be a `Variant) eg `CurrWS` and 2) you should use `Long` rather than `Integer` unless you have a specific need for 16 bit numbers (its faster, VBA does a background conversion to Long anyway).

Comment: Are you sure you have a sheet called `ExamSchedule`? - watch out for spelling, spaces etc

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I changed the two code lines 'Dim CurrWS As Long, StartWS As Long, EndWS As Long' and 'Dim Morning As Range, Afternoon As Range, Noon As Range'. That should be correct, right?

Comment: The name is right, it's "ExamSchedule" and there are no white spaces at the beginning or the end.

Comment: Looks ok. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: I've run your code with blank sheets (named as per your code and `Dim`ed as per our comments) without error.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I even tried the "Index-Method" for the "ExamSchedule" Worksheet as well and I get another error message: I added `Dim ScheduleWS As Long` and `Schedule WS = Sheets("ExamSchedule").Index`. Then I changed for instance `Morning = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day)` to `Morning = Worksheets(ScheduleWS).Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day)`. But then I get an "Compile error Syntax error". Why is the syntax in this case not working? I think I use the same syntax four lines above? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, it looks as my issue is almost solved. I run the version above again and now it works in my sheet as well without any errors. My only question left would be if you know any reasons why the code (using the same version listed above) didn't work in the beginning but then afterwards... But we may leave that question since it's pretty awkward and wishy-washy ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the default `Variant` type for the unqualifies `Dim`

What happens is the line

```
Morning = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day)
```

puts the value from `ExamSchedule` into `Morning` and sets its type to whatever the cell value type is.

When the line

```
Morning.Offset(0, 1) = Worksheets("ExamSchedule").Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day + 1)
```

is run, `Morning` is not of type `Range`, so it has no `Offset` property and errors

Using

```
Dim Morning as Range
```

etc should solve your problems.

**Edit**

to simplify a bit, try this
Use a variable for the worksheet
Be explicit with `Value` references

```
Sub SetData_new()
    ' SubModule to copy the data from 'Master_Plan' to particular sheets
    Dim Wochennummer As Long ' unless this is a global variable?
    Dim CurrWS As Long, StartWS As Long, EndWS As Long
    StartWS = Sheets("W_1").Index
    EndWS = Sheets("L_1").Index
    Dim Weeknr As Long
    Weeknr = 5
    Dim Day  As Long
    Dim Morning As Range, Afternoon As Range, Noon As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("ExamSchedule")

    For CurrWS = StartWS To EndWS

       'Set updated ranges
       Set Morning = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(4, 4)
       Set Afternoon = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(8, 4)
       Set Noon = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(12, 4)

        For Day = 3 To 21 Step 3
        'Subject
           Morning.Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day).Value
           Afternoon.Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day).Value
           Noon.Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day).Value

         'Category
           Morning.Offset(0, 1).Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day + 1).Value
           Afternoon.Offset(0, 1).Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day + 1).Value
           Noon.Offset(0, 1).Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day + 1).Value

         'Type
           Morning.Offset(0, 2) = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day + 2)
           Afternoon.Offset(0, 2).Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day + 2)
           Noon.Offset(0, 2).Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day + 2)

         'Specifications
           Morning.Offset(0, 3).Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 3, Day).Value
           Afternoon.Offset(0, 3).Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 5, Day).Value
           Noon.Offset(0, 3).Value = ws.Cells(Weeknr + 7, Day).Value

         'Increment
           Morning.Value = Morning.Offset(12, 0).Value
           Afternoon.Value = Afternoon.Offset(12, 0).Value
           Noon.Value = Noon.Offset(12, 0).Value
         Next Day

        Wochennummer = Wochennummer + 9
    Next CurrWS

    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Last question: I wrote my own version (quite similar to the code above) and for some reason, I get a "compile error: syntax error" at the lines starting with `Morning`and `Afternoon` but the line starting with `Noon` is fine for Excel in the following code:       `Morning.Offset(0, 1).Value= ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day + 1).Value
       Afternoon.Offset(0, 1).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day + 1).Value
       Noon.Offset(0, 1).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day + 1).Value` Why? (I'm using Office for Mac 2011)

Comment: @Patrick no idea (you fixed the `Dim` issue, right?).  I use Windows, not Mac so that _may_ be a factor, can't really help there

Comment: Yeah, maybe the Office **for Mac** 2011 is the problem in this case... Actually, I simply manually rewrote the lines not working and then the error suddenly disappeared as it should be. Strange...

Answer (score 2):

For everyone interested, the version I finally implemented looks as below. It works definitely fine on Windows and should work on Mac as well:

```
Sub SetData_new_my()
' SubModule to copy the data from 'Master_Plan' to particular sheets

Dim CurrWS As Long, StartWS As Long, EndWS As Long, ScheduleWS As Long
StartWS = Sheets("W_1").Index
EndWS = Sheets("L_1").Index

Dim Weeknr As Long
Weeknr = 5
Dim Day As Long

Dim Morning As Range, Afternoon As Range, Noon As Range    
Dim ExamSchedule As Worksheet
Set ExamSchedule = Worksheets("ExamSchedule")
    
For CurrWS = StartWS To EndWS
   'Set updated ranges
   Set Morning = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(4, 4)
   Set Afternoon = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(8, 4)
   Set Noon = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells(12, 4)

    For Day = 3 To 21 Step 3
    'Subject
       Morning.Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 2, Day).Value
       Afternoon.Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day).Value
       Noon.Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day).Value

     'Category
       Morning.Offset(0, 1).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day + 1).Value
       Afternoon.Offset(0, 1).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day + 1).Value
       Noon.Offset(0, 1).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day + 1).Value

     'Type
       Morning.Offset(0, 2).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 1, Day + 2).Value
       Afternoon.Offset(0, 2).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 4, Day + 2).Value
       Noon.Offset(0, 2).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 6, Day + 2).Value

     'Specifications
       Morning.Offset(0, 3).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 3, Day).Value
       Afternoon.Offset(0, 3).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 5, Day).Value
       Noon.Offset(0, 3).Value = ExamSchedule.Cells(Weeknr + 7, Day).Value

     'Increment
       Set Morning = Morning.Offset(12, 0)
       Set Afternoon = Afternoon.Offset(12, 0)
       Set Noon = Noon.Offset(12, 0)
     Next Day

    Weeknr = Weeknr + 9
Next CurrWS

ExamSchedule.Activate
      
End Sub
```